# Is it possible to Create, Delete or Update an Oracle DB user via JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jdbc

At the first stage i'm managing my app via JDBC, so i'm the resposible to build and validate all the SQL. But i was wondering if **JPA** could give me a hand on these tasks.

So, at this moment i've already have a DbaUser model, which was generated from the **DBA_USERS** table on the OracleDB, and i can actually list all of them.

However, i'm trying to manage to create or update more, but whenever i try to create using

```
 em.createQuery("CREATE USER C##ANTONIO IDENTIFIED BY Antionio123").executeUpdate();
```

An syntax exception is launched:  `The query does not start with a valid identifier, has to be either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE FROM.`

Could you guys enlighten me a bit more or pointing me to some proper tutorials? I've been googling but nothing concrete apprears on Oracle DBs system tables.

**Update1 (Thanks to @JB Nizet)**

After replacing the execution of the query from JPQL to Native SQL, i've got an error such as:

```
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE USER C? IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123").
```

I've replaced the hashtags with a scape character "...C##..." with "...C\#\#..." but the issue earns a different flavour:

```
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE USER C\? IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123")
```

... and i really need to send the "##" to the Oracle DB. How can i force these special characters?

**Update 2**

So...after googling a bit more, i've found out positional parameters, and i've also discovered that we cannot have named paramteres on JPA native queries. After this, i've tried:

```
em.createNativeQuery("CREATE USER ?1 IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123").setParameter(1, "C##ANTONIO").executeUpdate();
```

Which triggers: `ORA-01935: missing user or role name`

alongside with

```
Error Code: 1935
Call: CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123
```

Which tells me that this binding doesn't work. Is there another way to do it?

Kind regards and thanks in advance,

Sammy

Comment: Did you try with `em.createNativeQuery("CREATE USER C##ANTONIO IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123")` or `em.createNativeQuery("CREATE USER \"C##ANTONIO\" IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123")`?

Comment: I don't think bind variables are supported in DDL statements (`CREATE, DROP, ALTER` etc). Does the user you're logging in with have `CREATE USER` privileges?

Comment: Despite that this is a very interesting question, can you share the rationale for creating a USER (and particularly a common user) via JPA....

Comment: Hi @MickMnemonic, yes i surely have!

I'm connected with SYS as SYSDBA user, which means that i surely have the privilege to create them.

Actually, i didn't read anything about DDL statement and variable binding, which really probably means that the binding is not possible. I think that maybe JDBC will be the solution for it!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @MarmiteBomber!

What do you mean by "share the rationale"? (Sorry, i never heard that expression).

Kind regards,

David

Comment: Well I asked what you intend to do with this new customer. I'm avare that JPA time to time need a DDL (e.g. CREATE or ALTER TABLE), but never heard about CREATE USER. You will not get this new user as your conection poool user?

Comment: @Sammy I updated my answer. The point is to double quote the username containing the hash sign #.

Answer (score 1):

`createQuery()` expects a **JPQL** query. What you passed is not JPQL. It's **SQL**.

Use [`createNativeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) to execute SQL.

Comment: Hi JB! Thanks for you fast feedback!

I've replaced the createQuery for the createNativeQuery like so:

"CREATE USER C##ANTONIO IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123"

but the query is launched :

Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE USER C? IDENTIFIED BY ANTONIO123").

However, i really need the '##' on the query and i've already tried to use the escape character '\\#' but the query is only launched like:

sql="CREATE USER C\? IDENTIFIED BY Gbs22618")

Can you help me on this plz?

Kind regards,

Sammy

Answer (score 1):

To create a [common user](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#CNCPT89257) (prefixed with C##) you (i.e. your JPA connection pool user) need a [specific priviledges](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#CNCPT89398).

```
CREATE ROLE and 
SET CONTAINER
```

Those are *not* a typical privileges granted to a JPA connection, so I'm guessing you will fail with the creation of a new common user.

Additionally you **need to be connected to the root container**.

*The further example are plain JDBC called from Groovy, it should be easy possible to pass it to JPA if you get the DB connection.*

```
def stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CON_NAME') CON_NAME FROM   dual")

def rs = stmt.executeQuery()
while(rs.next())
 {
   println "container name=  ${rs.getString('CON_NAME')}"
 }
```

gives

```
container name=  CDB$ROOT
```

Note that if you are connected to a local DB, you get an error while trying to create a user prefixed with `C##`

```
 ORA-65094: invalid local user or role name
```

If both conditions are fulfilled, it is possible to create / drop the common user:

```
String cu = "create user \"C##TEST\" identified by password123 profile \"DEFAULT\" account unlock"
con.createStatement().execute(cu)
```

resp.

```
cu = "drop  user \"C##TEST\""
con.createStatement().execute(cu)
```

*Finally should be stated, that this exercise was done for the aim of completeness only. I do not see a real use case for a JPA pool connection to be granted such privileges and connecting the root container. The database maintenance is typically done not using JPA.*

Comment: Hi Marmite!

I'm pretty sure that privileges are not the issue since i connected to the ODB with the SYS as SYSDBA, so i am perfectly able to do it!

Thanks for your fast reply!

Kind regards,

David Cuevas

Comment: @Sammy, according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503), "In a non-CDB, a user name cannot begin with C## or c##." Are you absolutely sure that you're connected to a multitenant container database (CDB)?

Comment: Hi @MickMnemonic, yes i am connected currently to a CDB. But JPA should work in both ways...right?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a stored procedure in the database and then invoke stored procedure from JPA, thus you do not need to bother about caveats and syntax.

E.g.assume that JPA provider is EclipseLink

**Database stored procedure**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_user_creation (p_username   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                             p_password   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                             p_return        OUT NUMBER)
IS
   v_syntax   VARCHAR2 (256);
BEGIN
   IF (p_username IS NOT NULL)
   THEN
      v_syntax :=
            'CREATE USER '''
         || p_username
         || ''' IDENTIFIED BY '''
         || p_password
         || '''';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_syntax;

      p_return := 0;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20002, 'An error has occurred!');
END;
```

**Java code snippet to invoke stored procedure**

```
  try {
   Integer returnValue = null;

   StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery =
    getEntityManager().createStoredProcedureQuery("p_user_creation");

   storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_username", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
   storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_password", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
   storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_return", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

   storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("p_username", "SCOTT");
   storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("p_password", "tiger");

   storedProcedureQuery.execute();

   returnValue = (Integer) storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue("p_return");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("Error " + e.getMessage());
  }
```